# How to catch exception in Visual Basic 2015 not VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2015, error-handling

For the below code in Visual Basic 2015 not VB.NET I am getting a File Not Found Exception:

```
path = "c:\winpython\codes\output.TXT"
Dim sr2 As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(path)
```

How do I catch this error and show an appropriate message to the user asking them to not delete that file?

Comment: What is "Visual Basic 2015 not VB.NET"?

Comment: It is what it means I need a specific Visual Basic 2015 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to catch File Not Found Exception in Visual Basic 2015:

```
 Try
    path = "c:\winpython\codes\output.TXT"
     Dim sr2 As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(path)
  Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
```

Please remember apart from the File Not Found Exception you could also get any other exception while opening a file. So the last exception Catch is for that.
You can replace ex.Message with your own String message that you want to display to users like so:

```
  Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("There is an error while opening the File")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may need to import System.IO for the FileNotFound Exception though. @richgems

Comment: I laid out the code as pointed by you and it worked. Good Solution but this is not documented with Microsoft MSDN or anywhere else.